# Datatable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working in a project where I am suppose to be adding the Grid type facility in the data to be shown.

For that I am using the **Datatable** plugin of the **jquery**.

It is working fine and perfect.

I have only one concern that whenever I try to take the updated table from the server (via Ajax) the Datatable losses its functionality. I mean that whenever I load new table from the server, it shows in normal mode.

For that to work I have to add this piece of code like:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "<GIVE_ME_NEW_TABLE>",
    type: "POST",
    data: <THE_DATA_TO_BE_POSTED>,
    success: function(data){
        //data is fully prepared HTML string for representing the table
        $('#id_of_the_div_where_to_show_the_table').html(data);
        $('#id_of_the_table').dataTable({
           "bJQueryUI": true
        });
    },
    error : function(){
        //alert error
    }
});
```

So this is to be called on every Ajax call where the table is updated.

Comment: Not sure why this wouldn't work; you populate a new fully-formatted table, and then you call `dataTable()` on it. Seems like it should work. However, it's sub-optimal. What you should be doing instead is using the built-in Ajax functionality of DataTables to fetch the data only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively you can connect DataTables to an ajax data source via `sAjaxSource` param. You'll need to modify the server side script to return correct response. See [*ajax arrays*](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/ajax.html) and [*ajax objects*](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html) examples from DataTables doc.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/yoursite/ajaxTableDataSource",
    } );
} );
```